# $project or $group does not support <document>

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to run aggregate with projection but i get `NotSupportedException: $project or $group does not support <document>`. I am running version 2.4.4 of driver with mongodb v3.4.

```
var filter = Builders<T>.Filter.Regex(x=>x.Value,"/test/gi");

var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
       .Match(filter)
       .Project(x => new 
       {
          Idx = x.Value.IndexOf("test"),
          Result = x
       })
       .SortBy(x => x.Idx);
```

I thought `IndexOfCP` is [supported](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/e7a7e39da5f46b4eca28bea8986c658e72eccf7b/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Linq/Translators/AggregateProjectTranslatorTests.cs#L587).

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11):

The problem is caused not by `IndexOf` but by your projection. Projection should not include document itself, this just is not supported by MongoDB .Net driver.
So the following query without including `x` object into projection will work just fine:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
       .Match(filter)
       .Project(x => new 
       {
          Idx = x.Value.IndexOf("test"),
          // Result = x
       })
       .SortBy(x => x.Idx);
```

There are several possible fixes here. The best choice is to include in projection not the whole document but only the fields that are actually required for further logic, e.g.:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(filter)
    .Project(x => new
    {
        Idx = x.Value.IndexOf("test"),
        Value = x.Value,
        // ...
    })
    .SortBy(x => x.Idx);
```

If however you need the document object itself, you could fetch the whole collection to the client and then use LINQ to objects:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(filter)
    .ToList()
    .Select(x => new
        {
            Idx = x.Value.IndexOf("test"),
            Result = x
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Idx);
```

Use this approach as last option because it loads heavily both server and client.

Comment: the use case is just search where the most matching (by `Idx`) are placed at the top, so the `Idx` is just for sort. what's important is still the actual results and being the generic type, I can only access `Id` and `Value` so i guess option 1 is out.