# Selecting on document "outside" of join while filtering on documents "within" join?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two `IMongoCollection`s holding documents of type `Person` and `Animal` respectively.

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid PetId { get; set; }
}

public class Animal
{
    public Guid AnimalId { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public bool IsMammal { get; set; } 
}
...
Animal bootsTheMonkey = new Animal() { IsMammal = true };
Person doraTheExplorer = new Person() { PetId = bootsTheMonkey.AnimalId };
```

I am trying to write a query which finds "all persons whose pets are mammals".

```
var query =
    from pDoc in PersonDocumentCollection.AsQueryable()
    where !pDoc.PetId.Equals(Guid.Empty)
    join aDoc in AnimalDocumentCollection.AsQueryable() on pDoc.PetId equals aDoc.AnimalId
        where aDoc.IsMammal
    select pDoc;
```

Though this query is incorrect evidenced by the error message

> $project or $group does not support {document}.

From searching it looks like this error comes about from the use of `where aDoc.IsMammal`, more specifically the use of the `aDoc` within/after the `join` (Based on this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383632/project-or-group-does-not-support-document)). Though I am not entirely sure if that is the issue.

---

Overall I am trying to `join` two `IMongoCollection`s where the first's documents have a field whose value is the `BsonId` of a document from another collection. Then once joined I would like to first the documents from the first collection on the values of fields in the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do something like this (assuming allPeople is a list of all your Person objects and allAnimals is all your Animal objects):

```
var query = allPeople    
            .Join(allAnimals, 
                  p => p.PetId,        
                  a => a.AnimalId,   
                  (p, a) => new { P = p, A = a }) 
            .Where(PA => PA.A.IsMammal == true);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/8lw5ye

Comment: While this solution works with LINQ to Objects it does not work with MongoDB `IMongoQueryable`s. The same issue still persists.